# How to select features that equals to 159 different values

Tags: qgis, features, select

I am new to QGIS. My question is, e.g, I have a .shp that has 10,000 features: [image].

how to select features where the column of id that equals to 159 different values, e.g., selecting 
id=63703,63706,63708,63713,63733,63783,63705,63702,63745,65713,66733,64792....?

Comment: do you know where those features are in terms of spatial extent? I

Comment: You could write some Python code that loops over the features selecting ones with IDs it hasn't seen yet until its got 159.

Comment: @LaughU No, the ids that are going to be selected are caculated from Matlab.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for your answer. The thing is I don't know this function yet.

Comment: @mengyu is it a random selection? if so you could use QGIS with vector -> research tools -> random selection and specify the number of features to be selected

Comment: @LaughU No, the selection points are a vector with size of (159,1) which are calculated form Matlab.

Comment: @mengyu how does Matlab produce this vector? Maybe this could also be done in QGIS. In addition, to reduce clutter, please update your question so others won't need to read all the comments

Comment: So the result from matlab are those 159 IDs? If yes, "Select by Expression" is the easiet way "id in (63703,63706,63708,63713,63733,63783,63705,63702)" and all the IDs get selected.

Comment: When I first read this I thought you wanted *any* 159 features as long as they had different id values. Now I realise you have a predefined list of id values that you want to pick out. See answer.

Comment: @LaughU Thank you very much for your reply. Spacedman has rightly answered my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your IDs from Matlab into a CSV file with a column name the same as the column in your spatial data (for you, `"id"`) here. Read that into QGIS as a table. You'll get a layer with no spatial information which QGIS is quite happy with. I've called mine "FromMatlab" and it looks like this in the legend:

[image]

and like this when you open the attribute table:

[image]

My spatial data has a `PID` column, and that's the one I want to select on, so my (fake) matlab data has a `PID` column also.

Now open your spatial layer, and create a new JOIN (right-click, Properties, "Joins" tab) based on the id variable. Here's the dialog for my case, yours will differ:

[image]

When you've done that you'll get new attributes in your spatial data based on the relation with the table layer. In my case, prefixed with `FromMatlab_`

[image]

When there's no match on the ID, you'll get a NULL value. Then select features that aren't NULL. Use "Select Features By Value" and "Is not missing" for the relevant attribute:

[image]

And voila, I get the selected features selected:

[image]